# Terminal.app On macOS Doesn't Preserve Preferences

Tags: macos, terminal, operating-system, macos-high-sierra

I used to work with mac os a while ago an now I am coming back. What I noticed is regular preferences update doesn't work for at least Terminal.app. This happens on any High Sierra.

1. Start Terminal.app
2. Go to your `Preferences` either through a menu or `Cmd-,`.
3. Change something, e.g. use different profile as a default.
4. Quit application
5. Start Terminal.app again. Your preferences changes are reset.

What's going on ? Looks like a bug to me, perhaps I have missed something since Lion release.

Comment: Not a programming question though. But have you clicked at the bottom-button named "Standard"? The size must be saved using the Shell-menu and "Use settings as standard".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be that your preferences are "stuck." Preferences in macOS has been broken for awhile now and can sometimes get into a state where the app can't read changes made, or changes never get applied.

Try deleting your `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` file along with any `com.apple.Terminal.plist.lockfile` and `com.apple.Terminal.plist.<RANDOM>` companion files you find. Restart your system and try it again.

Another way is to look at the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` permissions. You may see something like this

[image: listing of the Library/Preferences]

Now if you run something like

```
sudo chown evgeniy.sharapov:staff ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist
```

And restart the Terminal.app, it seems to go back to normal and able to save changes in Preferences.

Comment: Ok. Looks like it. When ls `~/Library/Preferences` file `com.apple.Terminal.plist` is owned by `root/wheel` unlike any other `plist` file. Changing owner to `<user>:<group>` seems to fix it.

Comment: In my case, my user account doesn't have permission to `Read & Write` to `~/Users/{name}/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist`. Simply adding `Read & Write` permission and restart the Terminal will allow it to persist the preferences.